# Google shows different results for my brandname in their SERP

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing

When I typed `site:example.com` in Google's search box, it's displaying a different title and meta description, but the thing puzzling me is the site URL is being displayed correctly and redirected to my blog page.

However when I type only brand name `example` in the search box and click on the first result, it's redirecting me to different site.

Note: This issue is not limited to Google. It also for all major search engines. Also this is regarding my home page only, all other post pages are working well.

I don't know what's going on here. Anyone else have the same issue? How do I fix this?

**Update:**

When I fetch as Google, it shows me wrong data shown in following image:

[image: Googlebot vs. visitor view of the webpage]

Info: My website is in WordPress and hosted on Windows shared server. I'm using the "SEO by Yoast" WordPress plugin for SEO before that I was using "Basic SEO" plugin.

When I was using "Basic SEO" plugin I was working perfectly but when I moved to "SEO by Yoast" plugin after that I come to know this issue. Not sure if that upgradation causing this issue.

Comment: If you have a Google Webmaster Tools account, use Fetch as Google and render to see what you get. This is a good one! It could be a Google bug somewhere. A quick look did not come up with anything immediately.

Comment: @closetnoc, this is not limited to Google. It has also issue with Yahoo, Bing etc. I've already run "Fetch as Google and Render" but still same issue.

Comment: My apologies- you did say that. I mean use fetch as google to see if it still comes up wrong doing a fetch. If not, then you can submit to index. I assume that you are using a blog software- is it up to date? How about any plug-ins and themes? I rather suspect you may have been compromised somehow.

Comment: @closetnoc, I've updated my question after fetching as Google from Webmaster Tools and It shows different results. I also added website as well as plugins details.

Comment: Is your WP up to date?? How about themes? Please understand that not only can any plug-in be vulnerable, but themes too. Use https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search?execution=e2s1 to search for vulnerabilities for WP, all of your plug-ins, and your theme.

Comment: @closetnoc, all thing are up to date. I'm not sure, how to use the link above but I'll try to use this.

Comment: I hate to say it, but you may have been hacked. Some hacks add links, change the home page, and so forth. Being on a shared server, you should call your host and ask them to run an anti-virus against the server. There are viruses that change WP sites external to the site. You can fix the WP install only to have it change again.

Comment: I do not know WP at all. Sorry. I do not know that WP is the most hacked software ever by far. I did up-vote your Q to help give it attention.

Comment: @closetnoc, It's ok and thanks for supporting this question.

Comment: I wish you the best on this. It has to be frustrating. If there is anything I can think of, I will chime in.

Comment: Try to run https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/ then install and check strange redirections in your .htaccess with this https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/ then look in your server admin panel if there's some security scanner.

Comment: "different title and meta description" - completely unrelated to your site? What should the site look like?

Comment: @w3d, Yeah, when I type "webblogsforyou" in Searchbox, It should get title & meta description from my blog i.e, http://www.webblogsforyou.com. I'd added that details to my Question but someone had edited with "example".

Comment: @MMTac Questions about a particular site are off-topic. The moderator was trying to keep the question open by editing it rather than putting it on-hold. We can still see your original question and get your details as before.

Comment: @closetnoc, Ohh, Actually I don't know about it but as `w3d` asked, I clear out the details what it should be!

Comment: @MMTac Everything is fine!! Sometimes we ask for the domain name and other details. The moderator was just preferring to edit out the site details and keeping the question open. You do not have to do anything! Anyone should be able to see the original question by looking at the edit. That is really common here. The moderator was trying to help you get an answer.

Comment: Try to run your website with this tool http://aw-snap.info/ and put as referrer Google or Bing or other search engines, then "Check Url Only".
In your case, the source of the redirection is a .js file (probably you are victim through a SQL injection or through an unsecure source in your webpage). If you say the crawler to go to your site withour referrer, it's ok, like when you put your address in the address bar. So we can say for sure that the trigger is the referrer. You need to check on your backend as soon as possible and contact the support.

Comment: I don't know WP on Windows Server. I would say to you to look at .htaccess on an Apache Server, but I don't think you are using it right now.

Comment: Sorry, correct link http://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/ and here you can see the result of the search http://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/?tgt=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webblogsforyou.com%2F&ref_sel=Bing&ua_sel=chr&fs=0 (it would take 10 seconds to load).

Comment: @lucgenti, Thanks for pointing me out the cause. Can you say any procedure to follow to resolve this issue?

Comment: Start using some security plugin. Try Wordfence. See if it find something. Then I would start isolate variables. So, start deactivating all your plugins, then install a new theme uploading it via SFTP and use it. Install this and run it https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/ If your website doesn't redirect you when you come from Google or Bing, then start activating one by one and find the culprit. It if still redirects your website to anothere even with theme or plugin deactivated, then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: are you pulling in feeds from different sites? I did a site search for the navigation in your image(-site:macys.com "impulse contemporary clothing" AND "spring 2015 trends" AND "what's new") and I found it duplicated across multiple sites which redirected to another site. This tells me either you got hacked or you are in fact duplicating a majority of your page content and Google is discounting your "brand name"

Comment: @DavidGarcia, nope my site content is unique and I had not copied from any other site, blog or feeds. I also feels my site has been hacked because this is not happening to only Google but It's on other major search engines like Bing, Yahoo etc.